# Goto is considered harmful, but did anyone attempt to make code using goto re-usable and maintainable?

Tags: goto

Everyone is aware of Dijkstra's Letters to the editor: [go to statement considered harmful](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=362947) (also here [.html](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html) transcript and here [.pdf](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF)). I was wondering is anyone attempted to find a way to make code using goto's re-usable and maintainable and not-harmful by adding any other language extensions or developing a language which allows for gotos.

The reason I ask the question is that it occurs to me that code written in Assembly language often used goto's and global variables to make the program work well within a limited space. The [Atari 2600](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_2600) which had 128 bytes of ram and the program was loaded from ROM cartridge. In this case, it was better to use unstructured programming and to make the most of the freedoms this allows to make the most of a very limited space for the program.

When you compare this with a game programmed today without the use of gotos, the game takes up much more space.

Then it occurs to me that perhaps its possible to program with the use of gotos if some rules or other language changes are made to support this, then the negative effects of gotos could be reduced or eliminated. Has anyone tried to find a way to make goto's NOT considered harmful by creating a language or some rules to follow which allow gotos to be not harmful.

If no-one looked for a way to use gotos in a non-harmful way then perhaps we adopted structured programming un-necessarily based solely on this paper? Perhaps there is another solution which allows for the use of gotos without the down-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing gotos to structured programming is comparing a situation where the programmer has to remember what every labels in the code actually mean and do, and where there are, to a situation where the conditional branches are explicitly described.

As of the advantages of the goto `statement` regarding the place a program might take, I think that games today are big because of the graphic and sound resources they use. That is, show 1,000,000 polygons. The cost of a goto compared to that is totally neglectable.

Moreover, the structural statements are ultimately compiled into `goto` ("jmp") statements by the compiler when outputting assembly.

To answer the question, it might be possible to make goto less harmful by creating naming and syntax conventions. Enforcing these conventions into rules is however pretty much what structural programming does.

[Linus Torvald argued once](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/is_goto_the_root_of) that goto can make source code clearer, but goto is useful in so very special cases that I would not dare use it as a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314619/how-to-jump-out-of-a-c-code-block) is somehow related to yours, since I think this one of the most common situations where a `goto` is needed.