# How to jump out of a C++ code block?

Tags: c++, block, break, goto

This is what I would like to do:

```
{
    ...
    if(condition)
        break;
    ...
}
```

This works for a loop. I would like something similar for a simple block of code.
Is it possible?
Am I forced to use a "goto"?

---

I think such an extension of the `break` statement would have been a useful addition to C++11...

Comment: ...or to refactor your code with more atomic functions.

Comment: If you would post more code, we could suggest a better solution than using goto or other tricks.

Comment: If you're actually considering goto, you need to refactor.

Comment: put it in a function, and return. When people say "don't use goto", they don't mean "do the same thing you'd have done if you could use goto, but just rename the keyword to something else". They mean "restructure your code so you don't *need* to use goto"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm unleashing the wrath of a coding god against me right now, but this nice nasty macro could help people do this easier than before (based on @jleahy's answer):

```
//example use:
// { __breakable__
//    ...
//    if (condition)
//        break;
//    ...
//    if (condition2)
//        break;
//    ...
// }
//WARNING: use only with a standalone block. To make if, try or catch block
//         breakable use double braces
//         if (cond) {{ __breakable__ ... }}
//         try {{ __breakable__ ... }} catch (...) {{ __breakable__ ... }}
#define __breakable__ }switch(0){default:
```

Comment: This solution looks the worst under the implementation point of view (becuse of the preprocessor trick), but it seems the best under an expression of intent angle.

Comment: this has an added danger: you can add __breakable__ after an if{} and, without looking like it, it will bypass the logic of the if statement that you are attempting to make breakable. this only works with naked blocks.

Comment: Yes, that's what the warning is about. But I agree that no one actually reads warnings, so this is exceptionally dangerous in large projects where many developers are involved. For a private project it can be ok (you can create a custom to always use double braces with `__breakable__`)

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
do
{
    ...
    if(condition)
        break;
    ...
}
while (0);
```

I don't particularly like this style but I've seen it before. If refactoring is out of the question (could be for a massive block that can break a lot of stuff if changed), this is an option.

Comment: How is that better than a `goto` ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't know, it works but in this case the trick is more confusing than a goto. At least with goto you know what happens and why, with do/while (I imagine his code isn't short here) when someone reads the code first thinks about a loop then he must understand the reason of a while(0)...

Comment: A goto would be much clearer than this rather cryptic contrivance, and though I can't speak for the great man himself, I'm pretty sure that Dijkstra would prefer it, too.  Although he'd surely prefer a solution that avoided either :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way:

```
switch(0) {
default:
    /* code */
    if (cond) break;
    /* code */
}
```

(please never do this)

Comment: great idea, why not, what could possible go wrong... until this one, my best answer would be `for (int i=0;!i++;) {...}` but switch-case do not involve variable and seems better.

Answer (score 6):

In **C++11** the best way to achieve this is use a **anonymous lambda function** and replacing `break` with `return`

```
[&](){
    ...
    if(condition)
        return;
    ...
 }();
```

Note that `[&]` captures all variables by reference, if you don't use any just replace it with `[]`

Comment: Nice. However that `return` is misleading, because what the code is intended to do is effectively a `break`.

Comment: @Pietro You right!. Moreover, the main limitation of this method is that it can't `return` in the same way that a block does. If you need that your block to return then the `do while` solution is the right one.

Answer (score 5):

This one:

```
{
    // ...

    if (!condition)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will avoid `goto` to jump out of a block of code.

Comment: I agree with you, but in my case most of the code would have to be moved inside a further if block. Stylistically it would be better to be able to jump out of the block if the condition is true.

Comment: ya this is simple way of doing and more importent is understandability of your code than to be stylish.  To be stylish reffer Luchian Grigore's code it has no goto statement. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here just some additional possibilities:

```
for(..)
{
    continue;//next loop iteration
}

void mymethod()
{
    ...
    return;
    ...
}
```

Probably you should create sub-methods for the problematic block of code were you wanted to use goto and leave the block of code by the usage of return.

Comment: These cases aren't answering the question because they aren't simple blocks of code

Comment: Sometimes the question itself is part of the problem. Re-factoring the code in order to use sub-routines, instead of leaving a code-block probably would be the cleanest solution. So there would be no need any more to leave a specific code-block.

Answer (score 0):

I settled with using:

```
if (1) {
   if (1) goto End;
   ...
   ...
End:
   ;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

"I would like something similar for a simple block of code."

Use `return` after a condition is met, and `return` control back to the caller.

```
void MyWorkerClass::doWork(Item & workItem) {
    // ...
    if(noMoreWorkToDo)
        return;
    // ...
}
```