# shortest while once-loop condition

Tags: c, loops

sometimes i need goto statement to near-end of function, and to avoid feeling that i am in assembler, and to have strict defined block to escape from ...i use alternative, once-loop, and BREAK inside it, it looks better.

```
do {
     ...regular code with break possibility
} while (false);
```

so everything works well this way, as i wanted, but i wonder is there prettier way for this, because if code is bigger, you do not see in start what is loop for. what would be better looking idea.

like: `for (int i=1;i;i=0) { ... }` (it is clear in start, but not better looking from do while. or maybe `while (true) { ... ... ... ; break}`. the best would be `while (something) { ... }` where something is shortest and somehow obvious what it is for.

real world example:

```
#define onceloop() for (int iIi=0;!iIi++;)
void somefunction()
{                                                       onceloop() {
   if ((s=socket(AF_INET, ...)<0) { printf("create error"); break; }
   if (bind(s, addrIp,    ...)<0) { printf("bind error");   break; }
   if (c=accept(s, ...)       <1) { printf("accept error"); break; }
   ...usefull code on indent1 ...                                  
                                                                   }
   printf("something important just before the end of function");
}
```

looks better to me than:

```
void somefunction()
{  ...
   if ((s=socket(AF_INET, ...)<0) printf("create error");
   else {
      if (bind(s, addrIp,    ...)<0) printf("bind error");
      else {
         if (c=accept(s, ...)       <1) printf("accept error");
         else {
            ...usefull code on indent4 (or more indent for more ifs)...
         }
      }
   }
   printf("something important just before the end of function");
}
```

**update:** 
it seems that what i meant was a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314619/how-to-jump-out-of-a-c-code-block)!

and the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12315844/1303854) maybe is: `switch(0){case 0:`

Comment: If you need execute code only once, don't use a loop.

Comment: To be honest, none of those looks good to me. Seems to me a an `if-else` should do the job, not a "once loop" which to me would look a bit odd... Try to refactor your code with `if-else`. If you can't, then maybe show more of your code and someone here can help.

Comment: The point was to have BREAK posibility, you two could read the text not just title of question.

Comment: Can you give us a real world example, perhaps the shortest code you can find that actually shows your use case?

Comment: *"sometimes i need goto statement to near-end of function, and to avoid bad comments from someone who reads a code, i use alternative, once-loop, and BREAK inside it, it looks better."* How is some obfuscated `goto` any better than plain `goto`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Exactly. If a `goto` is what you want, use a `goto`. If someone criticizes your choice, ask them to make it better. If they can't make it better, then that's that. If they can make it better, then learn from them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for understanding well a question. But this once loop is really better looking than goto, for me too, not for other critics.

Comment: @MetNP Show us an example, because I find that hard to imagine. But if you're right, challenge the critics to make it better and, if they do, learn from them. If you have two pieces of code and disagree over which is better, I'm not sure how a third piece of code will help.

Comment: If you want an unconditional branch just use `goto` instead of a fake loop with `break`. `goto` more clearly expresses your actual intent.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, yes, but goto seems scary and unpredictable to myself too. when i see once-loop with break, it seems ok, predictable. will not jump in space, just to end of block.

Comment: At least `goto` allows you to provide a meaningfully-named branch target. With a fake loop and `break` your target is just the right curly brace and it will find one (perhaps not the one you meant) because your code is full of them. I find that a little hairy myself.

Comment: Another minor point in favor of `goto`, my IDE can easily find the branch target and everywhere it's referenced. Try that with a bare curly brace.

Comment: Are you just purposely trying to make your code difficult to read? Don't *ever* use that horrible style for indenting.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya why you even involving here if have nothing to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such `goto` usage can be replaced by a function:

```
void inner() {
     //...regular code with return possibility
}

void outer() {
    inner();
    printf("something more just before end;");
}
```

But it's better to use the `goto` where it is idiomatic. It's prettier and shorter and doesn't introduce a new function name.

> just inside inside c++ classes it tooks more code

I don't see why it would be any different in C++. But you can avoid defining a named function with a lambda.

```
void outer() {
    [] {
        //...regular code with return possibility
    }();
    printf("something more just before end;");
}
```

although, you might not necessarily avoid bad comments from readers this way :)

Comment: `goto` is idiomatic?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `goto` is the idiomatic way to express an unconditional branch.

Comment: yes this can be the best, and return is better than break, just inside inside c++ classes it tooks more code adding, and  "do { } while(0)" seems still better.

Comment: I have not done any C programming for quite some time. I would argue that all control flows can be written with `while` and `if...else`. Of course, with very complex logic, it can get unwieldy just as it can with indiscriminate use of `goto`.

Comment: `while` is idiomatic for loops. `if...else` is idiomatic for conditional branches. `break` and `continue` are idiomatic for unconditional jump out of loop / into next iteration. There is no control structure for unconditional jump forwards outside the context of loops. The general `goto` remains as the idiomatic way to do that jump.

Comment: @user2079303 I am trying to get my mind around the need for an unconditional jump. If you need to unconditionally jump to something other than the next line of code why do you waste time writing that next line (or lines) of code that you are jumping anyway?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah, perhaps my description of `goto` doesn't quite explain its use well. `goto` would be used together with one of the control structures which provide the conditionality. `goto` allows separation of the condition, and the target of the jump. The control structure provides the condition, and `goto` provides the target of the jump.

Comment: anonymous lambda functions, cool and i first hear about it, so i will mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical solution to:

```
#define onceloop() for (int iIi=1;!iIi++;)
void somefunction()
{                                                       onceloop() {
   if ((s=socket(AF_INET, ...)<0) { printf("create error"); break; }
   if (bind(s, addrIp,    ...)<0) { printf("bind error");   break; }
   if (c=accept(s, ...)       <1) { printf("accept error"); break; }
   ...usefull code on indent1 ...                                  }
   printf("something just before the end of function");
}
```

Is this:

```
void somefunction()
{
    const char *error = NULL;

    if (!error && ((s=socket(AF_INET, ...)<0))
        error = "create error";

    if (!error && (bind(s, addrIp,    ...)<0))
        error = "bind error";

    if (!error && (c=accept(s, ...)  <1))
        error = "accept error";

    if (!error)
    {
        ...usefull code on indent1 ...
    }

    if (error)
        printf (error);
}
```

Adjust as needed to match your use case.

Comment: Is `&%` a typo?

Comment: Nice, yes, error var is one way. Note, my case can be even more simplified by macro oncebreak(err) { printf(err); break; } and that is what i am fan of, simplifying unusefull (error related) code as possible, and focusing on right part.

Comment: @MetNP Please don't do that. It makes the code harder to understand. This code is already simple, compact, and straighforward. Why make people understand your macros?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz my real function performs all udp/tcp/server/client and it tooks a month to clean it to perfection, yes macros are maybe bad idea, but break trick was great help in many different situations.

Comment: @MetNP how would anyone looking at your source be able to figure out that `oncebreak(err)` is actually going to break the flow? He/She has to run around finding the definition of `oncebreak`. If they assume that it is a function call, they can assume that it definitely won't break. There is more to code that aesthetics. Readability matters _much much_ more.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya my newest favorite is `switch(0){default:`, and no macros, macros are evil :) ... and oncebreak had name that selfexplainig its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Based on your updated code example, I suggest you use `return` instead of `break` and remove `onceloop()` completely. You will also need to introduce another function:

```
void somefunction()
{  ...
   otherfunction();
   printf("something important just before the end of function");
}

void otherfunction()
{
   if ((s=socket(AF_INET, ...)<0) { printf("create error"); return; }
   if (bind(s, addrIp,    ...)<0) { printf("bind error");   return; }
   if (c=accept(s, ...)       <1) { printf("accept error"); return; }
   ...usefull code on indent1 ...                                  
}
```

You should consider taking this a step further and returning an error code rather than printing an error message. The caller can then determine what to do based on the returned code.

Two general principles come to mind here:

1. Each function should do only one thing and do it well. One function should be responsible for network communication and another function should be responsible for printing messages to the user.
2. Every line of code in a method should be at the same level of abstraction. Again one method should deal with the low-level network communication. Another function should abstract that to business logic.

**Original answer:**

A while loop is designed to repeat code until some condition is met. Usually this means repeating many times, although the condition could be met on the first iteration.

If you know before hand that the code will only execute once then an `if...else` statement is more appropriate than a `while` loop.

Comment: I do'n't see how this answers the question. While true, it doesn't relate to his question at all which is about how to avoid a `goto` in a less ugly way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Using an `if...else` is most likely the solution to "avoiding a goto in a less ugly way". I provide an explanation why the proposed solution by the OP is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, you mean wrap all the rest of the code in an `if` instead of using `break`? His issue is not code that executes once but code that he wishes to bypass.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "how to while loop once in c" I'm not sure how you can read this title as not about code that executes once. At the same time the OP wants to bypass some code as well. The use of a `while` loop is incorrect. The OP should use an `if...else` statement instead, possibly more than one depending on the exact details of their code.

Comment: I agree that it's impossible to recommend the right solution without seeing a realistic example of the issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sorry, but i used this 100 times at various situations, so i do not want situation-solution, just better "something" condition idea for once loop that i will continue to use regardless.

Comment: @MetNP I don't think that's possible. There's no one right answer to 100 different situations. If they're all the same, pick the simplest one so we know what situation you're talking about. If they're all different, you can't expect one answer. "I want the one right answer to 100 different situations and won't even give you one example so you know what I'm talking about" is unanswerable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok, i updated question with example, but i think that i  already found the simplest one, macro `for (int i=0;!i++;)`

Comment: @MetNP See my answer. There's a simple, clear, canonical way to do that. (And I hope you can see how hard it would have been to figure out that this was what you needed without your example.)

Comment: @MetNP Also see my edited answer for additional suggestions.